# How to set ids and names values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twig

I make a dynamic form but when i insert fields dynamically,names and ids not changed properly.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="dataRows">
<div class="fieldRow" id="template">
    <select class="items" name="items{{counter}}" id="items{{counter}}" style="width:127px; float:left;"><option value="1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"></option></select>
     <textarea name="description{{counter}}" id="description{{counter}}" class="description" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:209px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;"></textarea>
     <input type="text" name="unitprice{{counter}}" id="unitprice{{counter}}" class="unitprice" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px -1px 0;">
     <input type="text" name="quantity{{counter}}" id="quantity{{counter}}" class="quantity" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:64px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;">
     <select name="firsttax{{counter}}" id="firsttax{{counter}}" style=" float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px -1px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected" ></option></select>
     <select name="secondtax{{counter}}" id="secondtax{{counter}}" style="float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px 0px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected"></option></select>
     <input type="text" name="linetotal{{counter}}" id="linetotal{{counter}}" class="linetotal" placeholder="0.00" readonly style="float:right; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; background-color: #F0F0F0; text-align:right; margin: -31px -1px 0;">       
    <input type="button"  class="button remove"  id="btnDel" value="Remove Row" style="float:right; margin:-29px -110px; color: #ffffff; background-color: #d9534f; border-color: #d43f3a; padding: 3px 10px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.428571429; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;  border:1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none;" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

and here is my java script code for dynamic fields:

```
jQuery(document).on("ready", function () {
    initAddRows();
});

function initAddRows() {
    var template = jQuery("#template"),
        dataRows = jQuery("#dataRows")
        jQuery("#btnAdd").on("click", function () {
            var newRow = template.clone(true, true),
                fieldRows = dataRows.find(".fieldRow"),
                rowNumber = fieldRows.length + {
                    {
                        counter
                    }
                };
            newRow.attr('id', 'row' + rowNumber).find('[id]').each(function () {
           jQuery(this).attr("id", jQuery(this).attr("id") + rowNumber);
           jQuery(this).attr("name", jQuery(this).attr("name") + rowNumber);
           $('#itemscounter').val(+rowNumber);
            });
            fieldRows.filter(":last").after(newRow);
        });
}
```

my field values are items9,description9 and my {{counter}}=9,when i generate fields the names of fields are items910,description910 but i want the names and ids are items10,description10.

How i do this?

Comment: Always JSFiddle something as specific as this!

Comment: It's best not to use incremental names and id attributes, as it turns into a maintenance hell. Change the names to `name[]` and pass the values as arrays, and change the ids to classes so you can group elements, and then traverse them as needed in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your id are always going to be "descriptionXX", use `"description" + rowNumber` instead of `jQuery(this).attr("id") + rowNumber` (same with `"item" + rowNumber`).

Comment: when i add "description" + rowNumber it added description10 on all the elements